# Azure Network Watcher Reachability Report and Providers List

Tags: azure

I was trying to get Reachability report an Providers list. I tried Powershell commands and REST API.

[reachability report](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/rest/api/network-watcher/networkwatchers/getazurereachabilityreport)
[list available providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/network-watcher/networkwatchers/listavailableproviders)
[get-aznetworkwatcherreachabilityreport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-aznetworkwatcherreachabilityreport?view=azps-3.2.0)
[get-aznetworkwatcherreachabilityproviderslist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-aznetworkwatcherreachabilityproviderslist?view=azps-3.2.0)

None of these seem to provide the actual result

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/view-relative-latencies) to view relative latency to Azure regions from specific locations.

However, after my validation, the returned output of `Get-AzNetworkWatcherReachabilityProvidersList` is always null. I tried the commands `Get-AzNetworkWatcherReachabilityProvidersList -NetworkWatcherName NetworkWatcher_eastus -ResourceGroupName NetworkWatcherRG` within the Azure cloud shell with [NetworkWatcher region](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/?products=network-watcher). It's still the same.

[image]
It seems that ReachabilityProviders are not available currently or something wrong with the API so you could not get the content for the network watcher reachability report. I suggest requesting feedback at the bottom of [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/view-relative-latencies).

[image]